# Has anyone figured out how to make a javafx tableview act like a jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, javafx, tableview

I followed *Example 13-11 Alternative Solution Of Cell Editing* from the [offical tableview tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CEGFCFEB), but I want my `tableview` to act like a `jtable`. This means that when a cell gets focus, it is ready to be edited, and using the arrow keys or the Enter key should instantly commit the edit and move to the next cell.

This is what I've gone so far:

First, I added

```
table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

Then I tried to modify the class `EditingCell`:

```
class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String> {

    private TextField textField;

    public EditingCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void updateSelected(boolean selected) {
        super.updateSelected(selected);
        if (selected) {
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.requestFocus();
            textField.selectAll();
        } else {
            String value = textField.getText();
            if (value != null) {
                commitEdit(value);
            } else {
                commitEdit(null);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                if (!arg2) {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            }
        });
        textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if ((t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) || (t.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) || (t.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) || (t.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) || (t.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)) {
                    t.consume();
                    String value = textField.getText();
                    if (value != null) {
                        commitEdit(value);
                    } else {
                        commitEdit(null);
                    }
                } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

The `tableview` I got is a mess - I have to click Enter key twice to end editing, and it won't commit the edit but instead cancels it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I feel your pain...  I haven't worked on javafx tables in a few years, but here is a bread crumb that may be what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880494/tableview-better-editing-through-binding/7884249#7884249

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use arrow buttons to traverse cells in edit mode in TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330430/how-to-use-arrow-buttons-to-traverse-cells-in-edit-mode-in-tableview)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly that tutorial is missing some code fixes that were introduced later in the TextFieldTableCell class for the ENTER to work properly ([RT-34685 - Use onAction instead of onKeyPressed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096726) and [RT-28132 - Call requestFocus()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/rev/24e60f5070be)).

Here is a working example, it's a reduced version of the [TextFieldTableCell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html) code which also uses [Node.fireEvent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#fireEvent-javafx.event.Event-) to move to the next cell after the commit (mimics a KeyPressed event):

```
class EditingCell extends TableCell<Person, String>
{
    private TextField   textField;

    public EditingCell()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit()
    {
        if (!isEditable() || !getTableView().isEditable()
                || !getTableColumn().isEditable())
        {
            return;
        }
        super.startEdit();

        if (isEditing())
        {
            if (textField == null)
            {
                createTextField();
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
            // requesting focus so that key input can immediately go into
            // the TextField (see RT-28132)
            textField.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit()
    {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty)
        {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else
        {
            if (isEditing())
            {
                if (textField != null)
                {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else
            {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField()
    {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2)
            {
                if (!arg2)
                {
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        // Use onAction here rather than onKeyReleased (with check for
        // Enter), as otherwise we encounter RT-34685
        textField.setOnAction(t -> {
            commitEdit(textField.getText());
            t.consume();
        });
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(t -> {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE)
            {
                cancelEdit();
                t.consume();
            }
        });

        textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t)
            {
                if ((t.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) || (t.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN)
                        || (t.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
                        || (t.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT))
                {
                    // Commit the current text
                    commitEdit(textField.getText());

                    // Let's move out simulating a key press in this Cell
                    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(t.getSource(), t.getTarget(),
                            KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, "", "", t.getCode(), false, false,
                            false, false);
                    EditingCell.this.fireEvent(event);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getString()
    {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!