# javafx binding for edit tables Code snippet doesn't work for me

Tags: javafx, classcastexception

I used this code snippet to get my edit commit for my table done.
[UITableView - Better Editing through Binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880494/uitableview-better-editing-through-binding)

My problem is that i get an

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper cannot be cast to javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
```

in this line:

```
     SimpleStringProperty sp = (SimpleStringProperty)ov;
```

i have no clue what i can do about that.
I'm using just SimpleStringProperty values for my data class.

Here is the full code:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Supermain extends Application {



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final TableView<myTextRow> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setStyle("-fx-text-wrap: true;");

        //Table columns
        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmID = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        clmID.setMinWidth(160);
        clmID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));


        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmtext = new TableColumn<>("Text");
        clmtext.setMinWidth(160);
        clmtext.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));
        clmtext.setCellFactory(new TextFieldCellFactory());

        //Add data
        final ObservableList<myTextRow> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new myTextRow(5, "Lorem"),
                new myTextRow(2, "Ipsum")
        );
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(clmID, clmtext);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(5.0);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Get Data");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for (myTextRow data1 : data) {
                    System.out.println("data:"+data1.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        hBox.getChildren().add(btn);


        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(hBox);
        pane.setCenter(table);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 640, 480));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class TextFieldCellFactory
            implements Callback<TableColumn<myTextRow, String>, TableCell<myTextRow, String>> {


        @Override
        public TableCell<myTextRow, String> call(TableColumn<myTextRow, String> param) {
            TextFieldCell textFieldCell = new TextFieldCell();
            return textFieldCell;
        }

        public static class TextFieldCell extends TableCell<myTextRow, String> {

            private TextArea textField;
            private StringProperty boundToCurrently = null;


            public TextFieldCell() {
                String strCss;
                // Padding in Text field cell is not wanted - we want the Textfield itself to "be"
                // The cell.  Though, this is aesthetic only.  to each his own.  comment out
                // to revert back.  
                strCss = "-fx-padding: 0;";

                this.setStyle(strCss);

                textField = new TextArea();
                textField.setWrapText(true);
                textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);



                //textField.setPrefHeight(real_lines_height(textField.getText(),this.getWidth(),30,23));
                // 
                // Default style pulled from caspian.css. Used to play around with the inset background colors
                // ---trying to produce a text box without borders
                strCss = ""
                        + //"-fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;" +
                        "-fx-background-color: -fx-control-inner-background;"
                        + //"-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;" +
                        "-fx-background-insets: 0;"
                        + //"-fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 2;" +
                        "-fx-background-radius: 0;"
                        + // "-fx-padding: 3 5 3 5;" +   /*Play with this value to center the text depending on cell height??*/
                        "-fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;"
                        + /*Play with this value to center the text depending on cell height??*/ //"-fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;" +
                        "-fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%);"
                        + "-fx-cursor: text;"
                        + "";

                // Focused and hover states should be set in the CSS.  This is just a test
                // to see what happens when we set the style in code
                textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                        TextArea tf = (TextArea) getGraphic();
                        // System.out.println(".changed() index : "+  get_ID_from_table_index(getIndex()));

                        String strStyleGotFocus = "-fx-background-color: blue, -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;"
                                + "-fx-background-insets: -0.4, 1, 2;"
                                + "-fx-background-radius: 3.4, 2, 2;";
                        String strStyleLostFocus
                                = //"-fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;" +
                                "-fx-background-color: -fx-control-inner-background;"
                                + //"-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;" +
                                "-fx-background-insets: 0;"
                                + //"-fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 2;" +
                                "-fx-background-radius: 0;"
                                + //"-fx-padding: 3 5 3 5;" +   /**/
                                "-fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;"
                                + /**/ //"-fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;" +
                                "-fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%);"
                                + "-fx-cursor: text;"
                                + "";
                        if (newValue.booleanValue()) {
                            tf.setStyle(strStyleGotFocus);
                        } else {
                            tf.setStyle(strStyleLostFocus);
                        }

                        if(!newValue)
                        {                                                                          


                            System.out.println("EDITABLE???? "+isEditing());
                           System.out.println("TEXT:::: "+textField.getText());
                        //    commitEdit(textField.getText());

                        }

                    }
                });
                textField.hoverProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

                        TextArea tf = (TextArea) getGraphic();
                        String strStyleGotHover = "-fx-background-color: derive(blue,90%), -fx-text-box-border, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, 10%);"
                                + "-fx-background-insets: 1, 2.8, 3.8;"
                                + "-fx-background-radius: 3.4, 2, 2;";
                        String strStyleLostHover
                                = //"-fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;" +
                                "-fx-background-color: -fx-control-inner-background;"
                                + //"-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;" +
                                "-fx-background-insets: 0;"
                                + //"-fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 2;" +
                                "-fx-background-radius: 0;"
                                + //"-fx-padding: 3 5 3 5;" +   /**/
                                "-fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;"
                                + "-fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%);"
                                + "-fx-cursor: text;"
                                + "";
                        String strStyleHasFocus = "-fx-background-color: blue, -fx-text-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;"
                                + "-fx-background-insets: -0.4, 1, 2;"
                                + "-fx-background-radius: 3.4, 2, 2;";

                        if (newValue.booleanValue()) {
                            tf.setStyle(strStyleGotHover);



                        } else if (!tf.focusedProperty().get()) {
                            tf.setStyle(strStyleLostHover);
                        } else {
                            tf.setStyle(strStyleHasFocus);
                        }

                    }
                }); 

                textField.textProperty().addListener(e -> {
                    double height = 25;
                    textField.setPrefHeight(height);
                    textField.setMaxHeight(height);


                    //System.out.println("textfield Parent: "+textField.getParent().toString()); 
                });
                textField.setStyle(strCss);
                this.setGraphic(textField);
            }

            @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);        
      if(!empty) {
        // Show the Text Field
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        // Retrieve the actual String Property that should be bound to the TextField
        // If the TextField is currently bound to a different StringProperty
        // Unbind the old property and rebind to the new one
       ObservableValue<String> ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
        SimpleStringProperty sp = (SimpleStringProperty)ov;

        if(this.boundToCurrently==null) {
            this.boundToCurrently = sp;
            this.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(sp);
        }
        else {
            if(this.boundToCurrently != sp) {
              this.textField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(this.boundToCurrently);
              this.boundToCurrently = sp;
              this.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(this.boundToCurrently);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("item=" + item + " ObservableValue<String>=" + ov.getValue());
        //this.textField.setText(item);  // No longer need this!!!
      }
      else {
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
      }
    }

        }


    }

    public class myTextRow {

        private final SimpleIntegerProperty ID;

        private final SimpleStringProperty text;

        public myTextRow(int ID, String text) {

            this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);

        }

        public void setID(int id) {
            this.ID.set(id);
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.set(text);
        }

        public int getID() {
            return ID.get();
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly the thing you are casting (`ov`) is not a `SimpleStringProperty`, it's a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper`. Can you edit your question and provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: i upload the full code which includes the snippet from the other stackO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model class is missing the "property accessors". Consequently, the properties themselves cannot be used by the `PropertyValueFactory`. As stated in the [`PropertyValueFactory` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html):

> An example of how to use this class is:
>
> ```
> TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("First Name"); 
> firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName"));
> ```
>
> In this example,
>   the `"firstName"` string is used as a reference to an assumed
>   `firstNameProperty()` method in the `Person` class type (which is the
>   class type of the `TableView` items list). Additionally, this method
>   must return a Property instance. If a method meeting these
>   requirements is found, then the TableCell is populated with this
>   ObservableValue. In addition, the TableView will automatically add an
>   observer to the returned value, such that any changes fired will be
>   observed by the TableView, resulting in the cell immediately updating.
>
> If no method matching this pattern exists, there is fall-through
>   support for attempting to call get() or is() (that
>   is, `getFirstName()` or `isFirstName()` in the example above). If a method
>   matching this pattern exists, the value returned from this method is
>   wrapped in a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` and returned to the `TableCell`.

The last paragraph describes exactly your situation, because you have no `textProperty()` or `iDProperty()` methods defined in your model class. Hence the `PropertyValueFactory` creates a `ReadOnlyObjectWrapper` for you and returns it, instead of returning the actual property instance.

Note also you have the wrong type for the id column. The property is an `IntegerProperty`, which is a `Property<Number>`, not a `Property<String>`. Consequently that table column needs to be a `TableColumn<myTextRow, Number>`. This will make it quite a bit trickier to use the table cell implementation, as you need to convert between the String in the text field and the Integer that is the value for `id`.

In general though, write the class following the [JavaFX Property pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) as follows:

```
public class myTextRow {

    private final IntegerProperty id;

    private final StringProperty text;

    public myTextRow(int ID, String text) {

        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
        this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);

    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text.set(text);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text.get();
    }

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text;
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id ;
    }
}
```

and then you can define your cell value factories as

```
TableColumn<myTextRow, Number> clmID = new TableColumn<>("ID");
clmID.setMinWidth(160);
clmID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));


TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmtext = new TableColumn<>("Text");
clmtext.setMinWidth(160);
clmtext.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));
```

or, using lambda expressions (which makes the code typesafe and allows the compiler to check for the existence of the correct methods):

```
TableColumn<myTextRow, Number> clmID = new TableColumn<>("ID");
clmID.setMinWidth(160);
clmID.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().idProperty());


TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmtext = new TableColumn<>("Text");
clmtext.setMinWidth(160);
clmtext.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().textProperty());
```